# Enabling Delete and Edit in DataGridView

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

So, in VB, I have a form that displays data from a database in a DataGridView. In design mode, I have the checkboxes Enable Adding, Enable Editing, and Enable Deleting in the DataGridView Task menu checked. BUT, when I run the program, and try to edit or delete a row (person) in the database, it throws the exception, "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint." And when I close the form the DataGridView is on, and open the form from the main form again, the changes were not saved.

When I close the DataGridView form to return to the main form, I have this code:

```
Private Sub CloseForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.MembersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        MembersTableAdapter.Update(GroupDataSet.Members)
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I can't figure out how to make the edits or the deletions stick so when I reload the form with the DataGridView, it reflects those changes.

Here's the entire code on the form:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class AllMembersForm

Private Sub AllMembersForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GroupDataSet.Members' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.MembersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GroupDataSet.Members)

End Sub

Private Sub CloseForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.MembersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        MembersTableAdapter.Update(GroupDataSet.Members)
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

On the main form, the code is just the form.showdialog kind of code.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what is happening if you don't post the code (the one which is executed when the user affects the cells; for example: DataGridView-edition related events). What you have posted is not directly related (the error does not occur there) and, additionally, does not say too much as far we cannot know what are these variables/calls really doing. Please, post more relevant code and explain the exact conditions better (e.g., "this line of code calls a function which...")

Comment: There is no more code. Other than loading the DataGridView when opening the form. When the user pressed the little x at the top of the form, that code posted is what is executed. In that code I'm trying to update the data to what I did on the view. Which it is not doing. It is able to add a person to the data, but I cannot edit or delete certain data, just using a view...which I need to be able to do.

Comment: There is plently of more code; but if you use the Design View it might not be visible (not in the files you look at). There shouldn't be any problem when the user deletes something, unless some code is triggered in this moment. There might problems if you delete something from the DataSource directly; but deletions from the DataGridView are pretty inoffensive. Please, post all the code you have and explain the exact connection to the DataSource you are doing. I insist: the original code you posted is irrelevant as far as it is called when closing the form (after the error has been triggered).

Comment: If there's more code, I've not learned how to use it, nor where it is at. I know where the code is per form. Like, I have the options checked that let the user edit and delete members. But when your run the application, they don't seem to be enabled. I'm trying to enable those operations and write the changes to the database. I know I'm supposed to use the TableAdapter's Update method but I tried that and it gives that error.

Comment: And have you done some research with this error message? After a really quick search, it seems like there are plently of results; it is a more or less common SQL error.

Comment: This is a SQL error and from your configuration (the connection set up in the Design View and, apparently, working fine; with no more changes on this front), it is clear that the problem is in your DB (its structure). Here you have a post dealing with a similar situation: forums.asp.net/t/1185417.aspx (the equivalent event for you is: `DataBindingComplete` or can try `DataError`) You can do what this post suggests to catch the error (and thus allow your code to continue working); but you have to fix your Database anyway (or understand why the given deletion provokes this error).

Comment: Question: Is it possible that only your dgv is not updated but your data is transfered to the sql server? Can you see the data after open and close your program?

Comment: @ruedi When I open and close the form the changes don't save. Same for the program.

Comment: I have done many searches on this error message. None of the searches are the same as mine and I've tried a few things that I've found, but they apparently make no difference in my error, for I am still getting it. That post is wondering how to display a different message for the exception, which I can do. I need it to actually make the changes to the database that I do on the DataGridView. On the DataGridView tasks are check boxes that say: Enable Editing Enable Deleting. I have them checked. BUT, they are not actually enabling editing or deleting because I cannot edit nor delete.